# Swift 2 : sidebar menu with image full screen

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm developing an ios app using swift 2. I have a problem with sidebar menu. I set image for menu but it is not full screen. The image is not to top of menu. Please see bottom image. please help me. Here is my code . Thanks

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let blurimage = UIImage(named: "blur.jpg")
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: blurimage!)
    let blur = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light)
    let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blur)
    blurView.frame = self.view.bounds
    view.insertSubview(blurView, atIndex: 0)

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtKPC.png)

Comment: Can u pls add screenshot of the view/simulator?

Comment: this is screenshot http://i.stack.imgur.com/TtKPC.png

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a content mode

```
blurView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
```

There are a few to choose from

```
ScaleToFill,
ScaleAspectFit,
ScaleAspectFill,
```

One of those might work. Oh, and set the frame after it's in the subview. That sometimes causes bugs. Good luck.

Comment: thanks, but it is not working, this is screenshot http://i.stack.imgur.com/TtKPC.png  please help me,thanks

Comment: If you change the background color of the parent view controller of the blurView, does it stay black at the top?

Comment: no, if i change the background color of the parent view controller of the blurView, the top change too

Comment: Are you using Autolayout? If so, what are your settings?